# Editing Webpage Code in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: webserver, websites

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 as my server. It provides a small webpage in my Intranet. How do I view and edit the webpage code, where are the files located?

Comment: look in `/var/www/html`